# Ruby on Rails, return 0 instead of error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application and I'm often meet with the error:

```
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float
```

Or string or other variables type when I do some calculation or queries such as:

```
 upcoming = Appointment.where(:hairdresser_id => hairdresser_id).where('status = ? OR status = ?', 'accepted', 'personal').map{|app| app.price}.reduce(0, :+)
```

I think I understand the problem, but do you know if there is a simple way I can return 0 instead of errors like that, because it happens that maybe an Hairdresser currently does not have Accepted appointments.

One solution could be check if everything exists before doing the caluclation but I'm sure this won't be the best solution!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ironically, the correct solution is to check that everything exists before doing the calculation.

Comment: Try using `Enumerable#compact` before `reduce`. It removes `nil` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Appointment#price` is a db column you can add an additional check:

```
.where.not(price: nil)
```

If it's a method or a virtual attribute you could either convert the value to a float or int, which will convert nil to it's numeric representation of 0:

```
.map{ |app| app.price.to_f } # or `app.price.to_i`
```

Or you could [compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) the result of `map`, which removes the entries that result to `nil`

```
.map{ |app| app.price }.compact
```

Comment: With .compact I solved my problem! Is this the best practice or there are other ways to do it?

Comment: If you can previously filter out records that aren't eligible for summing up then that would be the more proper way. Have a look at the answer by @lusketeer as well, which may be more appropriate, as he's filtering out the records on on the db-level already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your associations are setup the way I imagine.

First, we could get the appointments by

```
Hairdresser.find(hairdresser_id).appointments
```

Then, we can filter by statuses

```
Hairdresser.find(hairdresser_id).appointments.where("appointments.status" => ["personal", "accepted"])
```

Lastly, we can use [`sum`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum) function to sum up the prices without worrying about `nil`s

```
upcoming = Hairdresser.find(hairdresser_id).appointments.where("appointments.status" => ["personal", "accepted"]).sum("appointments.price")
```